# Change font to in memoir to Gothic Textura Precius

Tags: fonts

I want to format my son's poem in a medieval font - namely [Gothic Textura Prescius](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/pgothic/). The following code doesn't work. What do I need to do?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,article]{memoir} % for a short document

\usepackage{pgothic}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\pgothfamily


\newcommand{\attrib}[1]{%
\nopagebreak{\raggedleft\footnotesize #1\par}}

\begin{document}

\poemtitle{The Long Patrol}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{``Look out! Here comes the long patrol team!}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
Oh I'm a long patrol hare \\
Nothing do I fear \\
When rats see us they scream, \\
``Look out! Here comes the long patrol team! \\
The ferrets all run \\
To their Dad and Mum \\
The foxes and stoats\\
Clamber into sea rats' boats \\
Oh I'm a long patrol hare \\
Long patrol is what vermin fear! \\
\end{verse}
\attrib{Akira Sims}

\end{document}
```

Thankyou :)

Comment: Your posted code runs without error in texlive 2014. You say "it does not work" but that is not very descriptive, do you get an error, if so what exactly?

Comment: Apologies, I should have said that the pdf doesn't show the correct font.

Answer (score 5):

After `\documentclass`, replace the next three lines of code with these:

```
\usepackage{allpgoth}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

LaTeX will create process a new Metafont just for you--something we don't see everyday.

Sparse documentation and samples may be found in your TeXLive distribution under `texmf-dist/doc/fonts/bookhands/`. I figured this out from looking at the file `allfont.tex` in the `pgothic` subdirectory.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

move `\pgothfamily` after `\begin{document}`  The package makes the font available but does not make it the default font. The other answer shows an alternative interface which apparently does make it the default. (or you could just redefine `\defaultfamily` to be `pgoth`